# Mongoose cannot set property of " " to undefined,Whenever i try to create a new entry.Eventhough the schema is declared right

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im building a support portal webiste.Where i have to record which user is raising the ticket.
Im using passport so i can get the username and _id through req.user.Im using **express** and **MongoDB Atlas** as my database.I have saved my database schemas on a seaparate folder called models.
Here is the schema file:

```
   const mongoose=require("mongoose");

const supportSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    type:String,
    comment:String,
    date:String,
    status:String,
    author:{
        id:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:"User"
        },
        username:String
    }
})

module.exports=mongoose.model("Support",supportSchema);
```

and here is the express side of things :

```
    //posting support to admin
app.post("/admin/support",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
    const data={
        type:req.body.type,
        comment:req.body.comment,
        status:"Pending"
    }
    Support.create(data,function(err,newsupport){
        console.log(req.user);
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            //add username and id to ticket
             Support.author.id=req.user._id;
             Support.author.username=req.user.username;
            // save ticket
            Support.save();
            res.redirect("/home");
        }
    })
})
```

As we can see in the schema above, i have defined author and inside author i have defined id.Im running into a error whenever im trying to create a ticket.It tells me "Cannot set property 'id' of undefined".
I even crosschecked by console logging req.user(which im able to access inside the route).

I have required the schema in app.js

```
const Support=require("./models/newsupport");
```

PS:name of the file is newsupport.
i have configured mongodb connection like so:

```
mongoose
.connect('mongodb+srv://saidarshan:R@mb02501@cluster0-wjhf4.mongodb.net/project?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
.then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to DB');
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR', err.message);
});
```

Please help me out with this.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Schema is declared right, but the you are trying to save author (subdocument) on the Schema itself, and not an actual document.

```js
    Support.author.id=req.user._id;
    Support.author.username=req.user.username;
    // save ticket
    Support.save();
```

You want to perform that save on the newly **created document**, and not the Schema. Like this:

```js
app.post("/admin/support",isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
    const data={
        type:req.body.type,
        comment:req.body.comment,
        status:"Pending"
    }
    Support.create(data,function(err,newsupport){
        console.log(req.user);
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            //add username and id to ticket
             newsupport.author.id=req.user._id;
             newsupport.author.username=req.user.username;
            // save ticket
            newsupport.save();
            res.redirect("/home");
        }
    })
})
```

Of course, another options will be to combine all the objects (document and the subdocument) together and do it all in one save so you can save yourself from having two queries to perform one task.

```js
const data={
        type:req.body.type,
        comment:req.body.comment,
        status:"Pending",
        author: {
            id: req.user._id,
            username: req.user.username
        }
    }
```

And you can just pass it to the `Support.create` and never bother about calling `save` method again on the created document.

Comment: @lonware if newsupport.author.id=req.user._id is used  .Wont that create new sub document .i dont want to create a new subdocument.Suppose we wil take one example     i hit the post route ,values are like so {type:internet not working,comment:something,status:Pending}.And this document does not have author field untill Support.author.id is executed.I want id and username saved to the same document created .so it must be like this {type:internet not working,comment:something,status:Pending,author:{id:12e3ree4556666,username:saidarshan}}

Comment: although ur second method worked out,combining all the documents and sub documents.Thank you.But my doubt is that if new use newsupport.author.id wont that create a new document as supposed to just adding the id and username to the same document which is being created in the starting of the code ?

Comment: No, it absolutely would not create a new document. It is only "updating" a document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where there is a new variable for the `Support` constructor to live while you're working on it. Try something like `let newTicket = Support.create(...` and then set `newTicket.author.id`, etc.